# cURL equivalent of file_get_contents & stream_context_create

Tags: php, curl, linkedin-api

Would like to make sure I am using cURL properly in order to replace a snippet of code which uses stream_context_create & file_get_contents.

Here is the original code from a LinkedIn code sample:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array('http' =>
        array('method' => 'POST'   //,    ? unnecessary comma?
        )
    )
);

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Here is the replacement code

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$response = curl_get_contents($url);
```

It looks like the original code is doing a POST, not sure about the cURL.  The replacement cURL code does "work" (whereas file_get_contents does not because of the allow_url_fopen issue.)   Still, I want to avoid future problems by verifying the replacement code.  I know very little of cURL and PHP streaming.

Thanks...

Comment: [tag:php] tag should be added to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` to make cURL send a HTTP POST request.